# Why can't you store the minimum value of int64 into a uint64?

Tags: go

In theory an int64 fits in a uint64, of course their numeric values will be different due to the first bit being reserved for the sign on int64, however why can't I do this conversion? it seems valid to me

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var randomNum uint64 = math.MinInt64
    fmt.Println(randomNum)
}
```

yields error

```
constant -9223372036854775808 overflows uint64
```

Here `math.MinInt64` is `-9223372036854775808`, technically a number that fits in 63 bits plus sign.

I'm mainly looking into this since I want to convert `8 bytes` back into a int64 with proper sign, but so far I only have seen functions that return `uint64`

```
binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(bytesArrays[0:8])
```

Comment: "4 bytes back into a int64" --> Hmmm, I'd expect 8 bytes.

Comment: @Keldorn what does your `-3` has anything to do? did you even run the code that was provided? there's a clear overflow error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this "conversion" doesn't work, is because there is no conversion in your program. Assignment does not implicitly perform conversion (except for interface types).

See the [assignability rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) that govern assignment of constant values:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - ...
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

In this case, `math.MinInt64` is an untyped constant, but it is not representable by value of type `uint64`, because it is [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) as so:

> uint64      the set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)

Conversion between negative 64 bit integers and unsigned 64 bit integers is possible, but you need a genuine [*conversion*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) for that. Yet still, you can't convert the constant value directly, because of a familiar rule:

> A constant value x can be converted to type T if x is representable by a value of T.

So, the correct way is to first assign the number to a *non-constant* value:

```golang
x := int64(math.MinInt64)
y := uint64(x)
fmt.Println(y)
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/qehJSU-sIte)

Comment: I never saw the problem as being caused by the constant, I was blindly testing with that constant assuming it was typed, the way you are casting between int64 and uint64 makes total sense, thanks for the constructive answer

Answer (score 6):

An int64 fits does fit in a uint64, but that's not what the code in the question does.  The code assigns the constant math.MinInt64 to the uint64 variable `randomNum`. The compiler reports an error because the constant is not [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by a uint64.

Assign to a variable first so that the rules for constants do not apply:

```
x := int64(math.MinInt64)
var randomNum = uint64(x)
fmt.Println(randomNum)
```

Answer (score 3):

Who says you can't?  Okay, the compiler says that, sort of.  But the compiler means that you can't put the *value* `-9223372036854775808` into a `uint64` variable, which is true; you need to put *the bit pattern that, as an int64, represents -9223372036854775808, but representing the value it would be seen as a uint64* into the `uint64`:

```
var randomNum uint64 = math.MinInt64 + math.MaxUint64 + 1
```

which [works fine](https://play.golang.org/)—or of course do what [GastroHealth showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700989/1256452).

> I'm mainly looking into this since I want to convert [8] bytes back into a int64 with proper sign, but so far I only have seen functions that return uint64 (such as `binary.LittleEndian.Uint64`).

We do the obvious:

```
signed := int64(v ^ 0x8000000000000000 - 0x8000000000000000)
```

(Well, it's obvious once you've seen it a few times.)

See [a complete example here](https://play.golang.org/p/AZs1Tt_2AJa) (I used big-endian, I like it better for human use).  Note that you can just do `signed := int64(v)` here; the flip-and-subtract trick is good as an expression where you don't already have a variable.